# db2 call one procedure and receive raised error from another

Tags: java, db2, signals, procedure, sqlexception

I'm calling a db2 stored procedure(p1) from java.

This procedure makes some inserts on a table, that has a trigger after insert. The trigger calls another procedure(p2), that raises an exception 'SIGNAL SQLSTATE '50000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error';

My called db2 procedure runs successfully, I should no get an `SQLException` in java caller. but I java code, I receive the sqlexception as if procedure p1 has raised it.

Why db2 acts like this and how can I prevent it?

---

Later edit

Another thing could happen.

Something could be broken in db internal kitchen on that database, so when i call procedure db2 actually executes procedure p2.

Unfortunately i don't have access to system where problem occurred so i can only ques what happened.

What do you think, which scenario is more plausible?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it is a trigger and the second procedure is run as a separate task?

I suppose your procedure code is something like this:

```
procedure1()
begin
//do smth
result = procedure2();
//do smth else
end
```

That's why you get the exception.

Comment: I receive that error because Procedure P1 makes an insert into a table that has a trigger T1. That trigger  calls procedure P2 that raises an exception.
In java code, i call procedure P1 and catch exception raised by procedure P2.
I just tested this scenario. Is this normal ?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be normal. If a trigger fails then the entire transaction fails if there is no error handling.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. I have another question.
How to catch error raised by P2 procedure, in P1 procedure ? (i need to set some status in a table).